# How can I nest a query as a variable in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

Obviously, SQL isn't my first language, so I need help with something that is probably trivial.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Airports.IATA_Code,
    COUNT(*) AS Departures,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Flights WHERE DestinationAirportId = 63384) AS Arrivals, 
    SUM(Flights.Tickets) AS Tickets, 
    SUM(Flights.Fare * Flights.Tickets) As Revenue, 
    AVG(Flights.Demand) AS Demand 
FROM Flights
LEFT JOIN Airports
    ON Flights.OriginAirportId = Airports.Id
WHERE AnalysisId = 2
GROUP BY IATA_Code
ORDER BY Tickets DESC
```

This query works fine, but I need to replace the hard-coded id of `63384` with the actual Airport Id.  This would be `Airports.Id` but when I try that, I get the following error:

`Column 'Airports.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

## Solved!

Just needed to group by the Airport Id as well:

```
SELECT Airports.IATA_Code,
    COUNT(*) AS Departures,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Flights WHERE DestinationAirportId = Airports.Id) AS Arrivals, 
    SUM(Flights.Tickets) AS Tickets, 
    SUM(Flights.Fare * Flights.Tickets) As Revenue, 
    AVG(Flights.Demand) AS Demand 
FROM Flights
LEFT JOIN Airports
    ON Flights.OriginAirportId = Airports.Id
WHERE AnalysisId = 2
GROUP BY IATA_Code, Airports.Id     <---------------------------
ORDER BY Tickets DESC
```

Comment: The SQL-Server syntax for a "variable" is `@myvariable`.  You would typically use this syntax in a [stored procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx).  Here's a good tutorial: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here... there should be a FK on OriginAirportId referencing Airports.Id. If that's the case, you can do an `inner join` instead of `left join`.

Also, try using `CROSS APPLY` if that's an option for you.

```
SELECT a.IATA_Code,
    COUNT(*) AS Departures,
    t.Arrivals, 
    SUM(f.Tickets) AS Tickets, 
    SUM(f.Fare * f.Tickets) As Revenue, 
    AVG(f.Demand) AS Demand 
FROM Flights f
INNER JOIN Airports a
    ON f.OriginAirportId = a.Id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Arrivals
    FROM Flights f1
    WHERE f1.DestinationAirportId = a.Id) t
WHERE AnalysisId = 2
GROUP BY IATA_Code, a.Id
ORDER BY Tickets DESC
```

I didn't test this code so please just use it as reference only please.

Or you can even try this...

```
;WITH AirportDepartureCount AS (
    SELECT 
        OriginAirportId AS AirportId, 
        Count(*) AS DepartCount,
        SUM(f.Tickets) AS Tickets, 
        SUM(f.Fare * f.Tickets) As Revenue, 
        AVG(f.Demand) AS Demand
    FROM Flights
    GROUP BY OriginAirportId
), AirportArrivalCount AS (
    SELECT DestinationAirportId AS AirportId, COUNT(*) AS ArrivalCount
    FROM Flights
    GROUP BY DestinationAirportId
)
SELECT a.Id, a.IATA_Code, 
    COALESCE(depart.DepartCount,0) AS DepartCount, 
    COALESCE(arrival.ArrivalCount,0) AS ArrivalCount,
    COALESCE(depart.Tickets,0) AS Tickets,
    COALESCE(depart.Revenue,0) AS Revenue,
    COALESCE(depart.Demand,0) AS Demand
FROM Airports a
LEFT JOIN AirportDepartureCount depart
    ON a.Id = depart.AirportId
LEFT JOIN AirportArrivalCount arrival
    ON a.Id = arrival.AirportId
ORDER BY COALESCE(depart.Tickets,0) DESC
```

Main difference here is that this code accounts for all airports (even those that did not have any flights). In your solution, you're ignoring any airports that did not have any departing flights. Perhaps that's by design but thought I'd throw this out there for completeness sake... ;)